# Calculate multiple columns in the same table with the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with orders(inside the order might be multiple products), when one or more product from the order is refunded then new row in the table created.

| order_id | price | refund_amount | payment_type | account_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000000003 | null | -$12.99 | account_refund | 12 |
| 0000000003 | $60 | null | account | 12 |
| 0000000002 | $60 | null | account | 12 |
| 0000000001 | $60 | null | account | 3 |

What I want to get is the similar table for say account 12 but having sum of price and refund_amount for the same order_id

| order_id | price | payment_type | account_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0000000003 | $47.01 | account | 12 |
| 0000000002 | $60 | account | 12 |

Thank you.

Comment: As per the question guide, please show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Hi Dale, the task is quite big overall, I have just pulled off the part I am currently struggle with. I have stored procedure that pays off automatically unpaid orders from Accounts balance, it creates Cursor for my table (actual table got 46 columns) and then checks if orders can be covered with accounts balance but now we have 'refund' feature that been designed ages ago and I have to add the difference to the Cursor and that is where I stuck. I have tried to write sub-queries but no luck.

Comment: have you tried using a `GROUP BY` query ?

Comment: " the task is quite big overall, I have just pulled off the part I am currently struggle with" - yip thats exactly what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a view instead of the second table, in which you get the columns you want using the group by command.
Like the following example:

```
CREATE VIEW table_2
as
select 
  order_id,
  SUM(price) as price,
  payment_type,
  account_id
from table_1
  GROUP BY order_id,
    payment_type,
    account_id
```

and then use it as a table:

```
select * from table_2 
  where account_id = 12 -- or any account_id you like
```